# Randomly select a value from a row that is not NA from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I have a data frame that has a series of values, some of which are NA - I'd like to at random sample one of the values that are not NA

An example below:

```
df1

col1    col2   col3
  1       4      NA
  2       NA      1
  NA       4      7
```

I would like a vector that then is a result of selecting one of the values from each row that is not NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` and select one random non-NA value from each row.

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) sample(na.omit(x), 1))
#[1] 1 2 4
```

Comment: Well `map_dbl` works column-wise and will return 1 random value from each column. We can use `pmap_dbl` for row-wise operation. `purrr::pmap_dbl(df1, ~sample(na.omit(c(...)), 1))`

Comment: Ah, whoops - good catch.  Thanks for the update Ronak!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `c_across` with `rowwise` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(Sampled = sample(na.omit(c_across(everything())), 1))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Rowwise: 
#   col1  col2  col3 Sampled
#  <int> <int> <int>   <int>
#1     1     4    NA       1
#2     2    NA     1       2
#3    NA     4     7       7
```