# Rowwise mean of randomly selected non-NA columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame, where for each row, I would like to randomly sample three columns (which three columns can differ between rows) and take the mean of those three sampled values. As an additional problem, I have many rows which are completely NA (and I cannot delete them due to other reasons) or only contain 1 or 2 non-NA values. Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984661/randomly-select-a-value-from-a-row-that-is-not-na-from-a-data-frame-in-r), I tried the following:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(inflo_mean = mean(sample(na.omit(c_across(everything())), 3)))
```

This doesn't work and I get an error about the use of `sample()`:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `inflo_mean = mean(sample(na.omit(c_across(everything())), 3))`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `sample.int()`:
! invalid first argument
```

I then tried to break it down into smaller steps and handle the different NA cases seperately and came up with this:

```
df_new2 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(num_NAs = sum(!is.na(across(starts_with("Col_")))),
         v_inflo = list(na.omit(c_across((starts_with("Col_"))))),
         inflo_mean = case_when(num_NAs > 2 ~ mean(sample(v_inflo, 3)),
                                  num_NAs == 2 ~ mean(v_inflo),
                                  num_NAs == 1 ~ as.numeric(v_inflo),
                                  num_NAs == 0 ~ NA_real_,
                                  TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

Again, this doesn't work either and I get the same error. I checked the data type of the columns, they are all integers. What could be the problem here? Or is there any other solution?

Example data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Col_1 = c(NA, 77L, 82L, 172L), Col_2 = c(NA, 79L, 
NA, 135L), Col_3 = c(NA, 81L, NA, 131L), Col_4 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Col_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
33L), Col_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 104L), Col_7 = c(NA, NA, NA, 106L
), Col_8 = c(NA, NA, NA, 93L), Col_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 50L), Col_10 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 48L), Col_11 = c(NA, NA, NA, 96L), Col_12 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Col_13 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Col_14 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Col_15 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: `
  df2 <- df %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(inflo_mean = mean(sample(na.omit(c_across(everything())), min(3, sum(!is.na(c_across(everything())))), replace = FALSE)))
  
  df2` try this

Comment: Suppose that a row has a few `NA` values. When you sample the columns to be averaged are these included or not? In other words, are you only sampling from the non-`NA` columns? Also, in the case that all of the columns are `NA` what result should be returned?

Comment: This seems to work for rows which have 3 or more non-NA columns or are completely NA - for the row with 1 non-NA value I get a weird result...

Comment: Yes, I only sample from non-NA columns. And if they are all NA, then it should just return NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapply` like below

```
df$inflo_mean <-
  mapply(
    \(x, k) mean(na.omit(c(x))[sample.int(sum(!is.na(x)), k)]),
    asplit(df, 1),
    pmin(rowSums(!is.na(df)), 3)
  )
```

and you will see that

```
> print(as.data.frame(df))
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5 Col_6 Col_7 Col_8 Col_9 Col_10 Col_11 Col_12
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA
2    77    79    81    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA
3    82    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA
4   172   135   131    NA    33   104   106    93    50     48     96     NA
  Col_13 Col_14 Col_15 inflo_mean
1     NA     NA     NA        NaN
2     NA     NA     NA   79.00000
3     NA     NA     NA   82.00000
4     NA     NA     NA   85.66667
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the row with 1 non-NA value: I would expect this exact value as output (i.e. 82). Where did 38 as a result come from?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Naming your sample data as `df`.

```
sample_mean <- function(r) {
  r <- unlist(r) %>% na.omit()
  count <- length(r)
  if (count > 3) {
    mean(sample(r, 3))
  } else if (count > 0 && count <= 3) {
    mean(r)
  } else {
    NA_real_
  }
}

split(df, seq_len(nrow(df))) %>%
  map_dbl(sample_mean) %>%
  data.frame(inflo_mean = .)
```

There are probably more concise ways to do this, but I think that the intention is clear and it does the job.

The input data frame:

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 × 15
  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4 Col_5 Col_6 Col_7 Col_8 Col_9 Col_10 Col_11 Col_12 Col_13 Col_14 Col_15
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2    77    79    81    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
3    82    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
4   172   135   131    NA    33   104   106    93    50     48     96     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Sample output:

```
  inflo_mean
1         NA
2   79.00000
3   82.00000
4   99.66667
```